# Check response of request sent to another server in php

Tags: php, gzip, httpresponse

We are working on speed up the website which is developed on Magento, in terms of css/js/images. To speed up website, We have put all our css and js on CDN to minimize the overhead of our server. Also we have enabled gzip compression on our server to reduce bandwidth.

On Analyzing the page, we have found that the Css/Js served from CDN are not compressed. After searching on the same, we found that the you can't change the configuration of another server i.e CDN.

Is there any method/way in PHP or Magento to check the content(Css/Js) received from CDN?
 So that, if the content are not compressed then our code compressed them and then serve to our website's page.

Comment: If you're serving from a CDN, then there is no "your server" which could do any of that. The advantage of a CDN is also to lighten the load on your server; taking on all that load again plus additional compression is quite mad. You should check with your CDN how to serve compressed assets; probably it just means that you need to upload compressed assets or such.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We appreciate your suggestion and following the same to upload assets on CDN after compressing them manually.